# How to remove library completely from Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I have added `AndroidSVG2.jar` file in my Android project. It didn't work the way i wanted, so i removed it, The problem is that, Its still there.

I deleted it, but whenever i run my project, it creates it again, and its creating conflict with my other libraries. Hence my project got closed with the following error message.

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x28 in tid
>   17039 (

I removed its dependency from gradle as well.

Kindly guide me how to remove `Library` completely from android project.

Comment: can you show logcat traces ?

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have just removed it from the `dependencies`. But, You also have to remove it from your `libs` folder. Try doing both and tell me whether it works or not.

Comment: Yes removed it from both places, Its still creating problem.